# The etymology of "catfishing" to mean to lure someone into a relationship by means of a fictional online persona

Tags: etymology

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catfishing) states that "the modern term (catfishing) originated from the 2010 American documentary Catfish. The documentary follows Nev Schulman, the executive producer, as a victim of catfishing. He had cultivated a friendship with what he thought was an 8-year-old girl from the Midwestern United States and her family. The woman with whom he had been communicating was actually a 40-year-old housewife. In the documentary, the woman's husband makes a comparison between the woman’s behaviour and a mythical use for literal catfish in the shipping of live cod fish."

My question here is that how does the above statement explain the use of "catfishing" to mean to lure someone into a relationship by means of a fictional online persona.

Comment: It explains that in the "Title" section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catfish_(film)#Title

Comment: Thank you for the link! The link says "Vince then states that his wife Angela acts as a catfish, keeping the lives of those around her interesting". However, it's hard for me to interpret it as his wife luring someone into a relationship by means of a fictional online persona ...

Comment: Maybe I am missing something? Sorry ~

Comment: @Maurice There's no direct connection. The word "Catfish" was used as the title of the film because people faking their identity online make life interesting for bored people. ***Separately,*** the term "catfish", meaning someone who lures people into relationships with a fake persona, was taken from the title of the film. It's an unfortunate coincidence that the term "catfish" was used with a different meaning in the title of the film than it's used today.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two concordant clues from Etymonline and Wiktionary:

[Etymonline *catfish*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/catfish)
(verb)  "assume a fake persona on social media for the purpose of deceiving or attracting another person," by 2013, from the successful 2010 film "Catfish," concerning such an experience, and especially the subsequent TV show of the same name which aired from 2012 on MTV.
**The film takes its title from an anecdote of fishermen putting a catfish in the tank with a shipment of live cod to keep the cod active in transit and tastier at the table.**

[only part of the long explanation is quoted here... see at the link]

[Wiktionary *catfish*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catfish)
(verb)  Etymology 2
**"From the 2010 documentary Catfish, supposedly inspired by the practice of fishermen keeping cod active by storing them with catfish (see sense 1) which nip at their tails."**

Comment: Thank you for your answer!